# В чём отличие между классами HttpRequest и HttpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, http, https, request

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, какой класс лучше использовать для отправки **POST** и **GET** запросов по протоколам **HTTP** и **HTTPS**? В чём разница между указанными двумя классами? Необходимы возможности установки **headers** вручную.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое важное отличие вам и не сказали...

`HttpRequest` - это представление запроса на стороне *сервера* в ASP.NET.

`HttpWebRequest` - это представление запроса на стороне *клиента*.

Поскольку вы пишите клиент, а не сервер - выбор очевиден :)

Answer (score 3):

HttpRequest это приблуда ASP.NET, работает с конкретным текущим запросом и "просто существует".

HttpWebRequest это класс для отправки запросов HTTP(S) любым методом, с любыми заголовками и прочим, это как раз что вам надо.

Не очевидное место: HttpWebRequest создается через WebRequest.Create который возвращает WebRequest, просто надо скастовать его к HttpWebRequest (если запрос http://), тогда будут доступны все свойства, заголовки и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!))) Буду юзать!)